# Transformation self adjoint proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on an inner product space $V$. Let $U_1 = T+T^*$ and $U_2 = TT^*$. Show that $U_1$, $U_2$ are both self-adjoint.

I understand these just as innate properties. I don't really understand how they're supposed to be proved. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the properties of the adjoint operation $S \mapsto S^*$. We now that for any $S_1, S_2 \in L(V)$, we have
$$ (S_1 + S_2)^* = S_1^* + S_2^*, \quad (S_1S_2)^* = S_2^*S_1^*, \quad S_1^{**} = S_1 $$
To check, whether, say, $U_1$ is self-adjoint, compute $U_1^*$. We have
$$ U_1^* = (T+T^*)^* = T^* + T^{**} = T^* + T = T + T^* = U_1 $$
For $U_2$ we have
$$ U_2^* = (TT^*)^* = T^{**}T^* = TT^* = U_2 $$